# inserting multiple checkbox values using implode function in same column in cakephp 2.8.2

Tags: cakephp

Hi i am tyring to insert multiple checkbox values in same column using cakephp but i have error "Trying to get property of non-object [APP\Model\Task.php, line 34]" that is at Model

```
if($this->request->data['Task']['Feel']!=0) 
{
    $this->data['Task']['Feel'] = implode(',', $this->data['Task']['Feel']);
}
```

**My view**

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->css('style');
echo $this->Form->create('task'); 
?>
<table align= "center">
<div class="checkbox">
<tr>
<td>Name 1</td>
<td>
<?php
$list = array('1' => 'Happy', '2' => 'Laugh', '3' => 'Sad', '4' => 'Angry','5'=>'Cry');
echo $this->Form->input('Feel',array('label' => false,'options' => $list,'multiple'=>'checkbox'));
?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name 2</td>
<td>
<?php
$list = array('6' => 'Happy', '7' => 'Laugh', '8' => 'Sad', '9' => 'Angry','10'=>'Cry');
echo $this->Form->input('Feel',array('label' => false,'options' =>     $list,'multiple'=>'checkbox'));
?>
</td>
</tr>
</div>
</table>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

**My Model**

```
    class Task extends AppModel 
{
    function beforeValidate() 
    {
        if($this->request->data['Task']['Feel']!=0) 
        {
        $this->data['Task']['Feel'] = implode(',', $this->data['Task']['Feel']);
        }
    }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
class TaskController extends AppController 
{
    public $uses = array();
    public $helpers = array('Html','Form');
    public $components =array('Flash');
    public function task($id=null)
    {
    $this->Task->create();
    if ($this->Task->save($this->request->data)) 
        {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your task has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'task'));
        }else
        {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add the task.'));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I remove this error and how can I solve it?
Please any body help me....

Comment: Look here ```if($this->request->data['Task']['Feel']!=0) ``` in model use simple ```$this->data['Task']['Feel']!=0```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Form->create('task');
```

This should be

```
echo $this->Form->create('Task');
```

Comment: Thank u for your help

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

```
echo $this->Form->create('task');
```

Should be:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Task');
```

And:

```
if($this->request->data['Task']['Feel']!=0)
```

Should be:

```
if($this->data['Task']['Feel']!=0)
```

Or even better:

```
if($this->data['Task']['Feel'])
```

Comment: Thank u for your help but

Comment: Thank u for your help but it don't works... it says "Unable to add the task" it don't insert the checkbox values

Comment: @Mathanlal set debug level to `2`, that should display error.